# Laravel hasManyThrough get the intermediate model on query results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a Laravel 9 project. I have a model called `PingtreeGroup` that I need to get all associated `Pingtree` models through my `PingtreeEntry` model.

My query is working as expected and is joining the furthest model which is my `Pingtree`.

The problem I've encountered is that I also need to join the actual `PingtreeEntry` model as well to the furthest model, or somehow get the `PingtreeEntry` model with it.

This is my current `PingtreeGroup` model relationship:

```php
/**
 * Get the pingtrees for the model
 */
public function pingtrees()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Pingtree::class,
        PingtreeEntry::class,
        'pingtree_group_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'pingtree_id'
    );
}
```

Then my query:

```php
$pingtreeGroups = PingtreeGroup::where('company_id', $company_id)
                                ->with('pingtrees')
                                ->withCount('pingtrees')
                                ->paginate($request->input('perPage', 10));
```

How could I achieve this desired result?

Comment: just add inside `PingtreeGroup` another relationship to `PingtreeEntry`, for example `pingtree_entries()` and than you can add multiple relationship in `->with('pingtrees', 'pingtree_entries')`

Comment: Sure, but how would the `pingtree_entries` be associated with a `pingtree`? I need the Entry's ID and other data on the pingtree model through the group.

Comment: Have you tried using the pivot property? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: No because I'm using a `hasManyThrough` relationship which supposedly doesn't work with pivots.

Answer (score 0):

I assume PingtreeEntry-Pingtree has one-on-one relationship.

```
// in Pingtree model add this relationship 
public function pingtree_entry()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Pingtree::class);
}
```

And update your query to call this relationship

```
$pingtreeGroups = PingtreeGroup::where('company_id', $company_id)
    ->with('pingtrees', 'pingtrees.pingtree_entry')
    ->withCount('pingtrees')
    ->paginate($request->input('perPage', 10));
```

Now from a single PingtreeGroup, you can get multiple Pingtree.
And inside each of this Pingtree, you can fetch data from PingtreeEntry.

For example lets do get a single PingtreeGroup

```
$pingtreeGroup = PingtreeGroup::where('company_id', $company_id)
    ->with('pingtrees', 'pingtrees.pingtree_entry')
    ->first();

// get the first Pingtree
$pingTree = $pingtreeGroup->pingtrees()->first();

// and inside this Pingtree , you get fetch PingtreeEntry
$pingtreeEntry = $pingTree->pingtree_entry;
```

Now you can get any kind of data inside this PingtreeEntry.

I hope this can help you out.

Comment: you can also change the pingtree - pingtree_entry relationship to many using `->belongsToMany()`, which resulting multiple PingtreeEntry inside each of single PingTree